# Iterating JSON in a django template

Tags: json, django, for-loop, django-templates, iteration

I have a json coming from a view in below format in a variable(`AllUsers`) :

```
{
  "msg": "data found.",
  "user": [
    {
      "fname": "aaa",
      "lname": "aaa",
      "add": "add1",
      "city": "city1",
    },
    {
      "fname": "aaa2",
      "lname": "aaa2",
      "add": "add2",
      "city": "city2",
    }
  ],
  "data_status": "active",
  "error": false
}
```

I need to iterate through this JSON in my template and print in below format.So ideally my loop should run 2 times in this case.

```
name : aaa
name : aaa2
```

I tried :

```
{% for myusers in AllUsers %}
       name : {{ user.fname}}
{% end for%}
```

AND

```
{%with myusers=AllUsers.user%}
{% for user in myusers %}
name : {{ user.fname}}  
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

But both of them are not working as loops are not iterating even once.In one of SO threads i read *....You shouldn't "convert it to JSON"....* but this is not in my hand...i just get the JSON.

`Views` looks like this :

```
def somefucn(request):
    data = {
        "msg": "data found.",
        "AllUsers": AllUser                    ## This is where the above JSON resides
        "data_status": "active",
        "error": false
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'path/to/Template.html', data)
```

Where am i going wrong in the iteration? Please help..

Comment: What type have AllUser? Is it string type?

Comment: @user2172884 : JSON....its picked from `redis` via `json.loads`

Comment: Can you post exact output of `repr(AllUser)` and `type(AllUser)`?

Comment: Tried in VIEW = > print => `JSON` i posted above and  type => `<class 'django.http.response.JsonResponse'>`,

Comment: Can you post whole code generating `AllUser`? `JsonResponse` shouldn't be type of object returned by `json.loads` so you're definetly doing something different than described in comment above

Comment: @GwynBleidD : I can't post that code but if it helps, JSON is the same i posted above and after that it simple does `return JsonResponse(user_data)`

Comment: Why you're using JsonResponse here? It's an HTTP Response, not an object that you can use inside your template or python code. Use `json.loads` instead, if `user_data` is string containing unparsed JSON data, if `user_data` is already parsed, just return it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89594/discussion-between-gwynbleidd-and-noobeditor).

Comment: Hello, Are you still looking for solution for this problem? I've faced same problem some times ago, if you interested i can post own solution as answer

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew : sure..post it...always helps! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solution was much easier than I thought:

Let's say you have some JSON like POST request with schema like:

```
"success": true,
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": "76735142",
      "username": "user11_01",
      "email": "test11@test.com",
      "isTest": false,
      "create_at": "2016-01-29T15:41:16.901Z",
      "isBlocked": false
    }
```

(All values in the scheme above were given as example)

And you know that to get this response correctly you need next variables in your post body:

```
{
"id": "",
"pass_code": "",
"search_for": "",
}
```

Next you need to send POST request with needed values to the API server:

First you need to install necessary components (from your virtualenv):

```
pip install requests[security]
```

[security] flag is needed in order to successful response from HTTPS

**VIEWS.PY**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def get_user(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    post_data = {'id': '1234', 'pass_code': 'pass', 'search_for': '123456'}
    response = requests.post('https://example.com/api/', data=post_data)
    args['contents'] = response.json()
    return render_to_response('your_templae.html', args)
```

**YOUR_TEMPLATE.HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testing JSON response</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
{% for user in contents.users %}
    {{ user.userId}}<br>
    {{ user.username}}<br>
{% empty %}
    Nothing found
{% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's it! Have a nice work!
If you mess around you can event fetch headers of this request ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use template filter to load json in the template.

Create a file mytags.py as `<your-app>/templatetags/mytags.py`

The content of `mytags.py` as:

```
import json

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def loadjson(data):
    return json.loads(data)
```

Then in your django .htm/.html template load the tags. eg:

```
{% load mytags %}


{% for foo in YourJsonData|loadjson %}
    {{ foo.something }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps.

For more info about advanced templating see: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html#extending-the-template-system